# How can i visualize three nested List?

Tags: java, xhtml, primefaces

I have a this structure:

```
List< List< tracciato >> dataTot;
```

with

```
public class tracciato {

   String              comando = "";
   String              nome;
   int                 posizione;
   String              tipo;
   ArrayList< String > dati = new ArrayList<>(); //  an other list 

   public tracciato() {
   }
}
```

note that also inside the class tracciato there is an other list....
they are 3 list nested...can I use dataTable? 
thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: sounds like an opportunity to create the 3d 'data' environments from the movie hackers.

Comment: I will suggest you should consider using 2d/3d array instead of generics in such case.

Comment: A list of list of list is a tree, why using a tree? What's the true problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like a `Tree`, that would look on the Console maybe something like this:

```
List1
-List1_1
-- commando:
-- nome
---List1_1_1

and so on.
```

However if you want it to be graphical there is also a `Tree` Implementations for Java Available.